# Django model inheritance: Delete subclass keep superclass

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

When dealing whith model inheritance in django is it possible to remove a instance of model subclass, without removing the superclass itself?

Using the [Django example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance), can you remove just the `Resturaunt` object and retain the `Place` object?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yesterday I was looking for an answer to this question and I came up with this solution, which was enough for my problem but could be scaled up as needed.

Assuming you have a Restaurant and a Place django models, the way to delete a restaurant only without touching the row inside the Place's table is creating a "fake" Restaurant model like this:

```
class FakeRestaurant(models.Model):
    place_ptr = models.PositiveIntegerField(db_column="place_ptr_id", primary_key=True)
    serves_hot_dogs = models.BooleanField()
    serves_pizza = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = Restaurant._meta.app_label
        db_table = Restaurant._meta.db_table
        managed = False
```

Now, you can retrieve objects from that table as if it had no bound external relationship:

```
place = Place.objects.get(pk=1)
restaurant = Restaurant.objects.get(pk=1)
fake_restaurant = FakeRestaurant.objects.get(pk=1)
fake_restaurant.delete()
```

fake_restaurant and restaurant won't exist anymore, place will remain untouched.

Cheers,
Davide

Comment: Please note the "managed" options inside the Meta class set to True

Comment: I mean, set to False. The editor didn't keep the correct indentation.
Thanks :D

Answer (score 9):

In Django 1.9 parameter `keep_parents` was added to model `delete()` function, so to keep parents just call:

```
restaurant.delete(keep_parents=True)
```

Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.delete

**UPDATE:**

Apparently, this feature is **not** working properly in Django 1.9, please see the comments.

Comment: I just tried this and there appears to be a bug in the 1.9 implementation. All relationships to the parent object are removed. This has been fixed in later versions https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27407