# Django model multi-table inheritance: create super instance of existing instance (cast)

Tags: python, django, inheritance

I have the following class hierarchy in Django, using multi-table inheritance:

```
class Vehicle(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(blank=True)

class Car(Vehicle):
   color = models.CharField(blank=True)
```

As I use multi-table inheritance, at the database level, there two database tables, one for Vehicle and another for Car. There is also a OneToOne relationship between them.

I have some Car objects on my database. I want to cast these objects to Vehicle, and delete the "Car" part of them. I want that none of these "ex-Cars" appear if I do Car.objects.all().

To obtain the superclass instance, I can do:

```
car = Car()
vehicle = car.vehicle
```

But how can I safely delete the "car" object without deleting the "vehicle" object?

I have found some answers related to downcasting (creating a child class instance from a superclass instance and storing it on db, see: [Django model inheritance: create sub-instance of existing instance (downcast)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4064808/django-model-inheritance-create-sub-instance-of-existing-instance-downcast)), but I have not found an answer yet about this case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django model inheritance: Delete subclass keep superclass](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10287169/django-model-inheritance-delete-subclass-keep-superclass)